# Finding angular velocity of a frame given an angular velocity in another frame

Tags: rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, vectors, centrifugal-force, coriolis-effect

I was trying to understand the Earth's frame of reference. You stick a coordinate system on the surface of the Earth and due to the Earth's rotation the coordinate rotates with respect to the axis of the Earth. It is also obvious that the coordinate axes have some rotation around the origin for example if you stick the coordinate system at the poles the angular velocity is in the z direction and if you place it at the equation its different.

But it's unclear how you can mathematically find this. I was reading Wikipedia and was watching an HC Verma lecture. There, when they were writing the equation of motion in the Earth frame they wrote it like this.

$$m\overrightarrow{a}=m\omega^2R-m\overrightarrow{\omega}\times(\overrightarrow{\omega}\times r)-2m\overrightarrow{\omega}\times \overrightarrow{v}$$

where $R$ is the radius of the Earth and small $r$ is the position vector wrt to your frame on the surface.

The first term comes from the rotation of the origin so to account for the translational motion of the origin we apply pseudo force in the opposite direction. The next two terms are coriolis and centrifugal force both of them are fine.

But what bothers me is the omega, that omega comes from the rotation of the Earth. How can we take that vector shift it to the origin and say that the angular velocity of the frame is the same omega that depicts the rotation of the Earth? In which way does the angular velocity of the vector can be shifted that depicts the rotation of the frame with respect to the origin??

I don't want answers that say due to the invariance of vectors they can be translated, but these are different quantities. And I am not looking for a formal proof with inertia tensor and stuff like that. I want a logical explanation, it's fine if it's not rigorous.

[image]

and

[image]